# How do i join a polygon's (cell shaped) attribute to another polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, fields-attributes, vector-grid

I have a grid shaped polygon which includes population data inside every cell (1km*1km) and I'd like to transfer this population data to my other polygon that are the districts of a city to find a total population of any district.

[image]

Comment: How do you intend to apportion cells that intersect two or more district polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) of grid polygons. Set split policy/Use Ratio Policy on the population field so if the grid cell is split or resized the population will follow the change in area.
2. [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) the feature layer from above with the district polygons.
3. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) with district name/ids as dissolve field and population as statistics field.

If the grid cells do not cover all districts some parts will be missing. In that case you can use spatial join to join data back to the original district polygons.

Comment: I will try after christmas and will respond. Thank you for your interest